# Connection timeout when accessing Github

Tags: git

I have exactly the same problem as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849986/connection-timeout-when-accessing-github

So I'll just copy & paste:

> I have some weird problems. When I try to **log in** my **Github**
>   account, I get a "net::**ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**" error.
>
> I **tried with Chrome, Firefox and Opera**. In Firefox, if a clean the
>   cache and offline data, it works for a while. Then I can log in, but I
>   still can't create a Github repository, even if I clear the cache
>   again.
>
> My **friend**, in the **same network**, with Windows, **can** do
>   whatever he wants on Github's web site, but I can't. I **tried** many
>   **DNS** servers, I tried not to set it (my friend doesn't), but it's still **not working**.
>
> My OS: **Ubuntu x64 12.04**
>
> Ideas, please. And thanks.

Also, I can clone any repo but I can't push. I had to change to https://codeplane.com/ due to this problem, but I want to understand why it happens.

EDIT: I could clone one repo, but the other one just hangs at this point:

```
felipelalli@felipelalli-Studio-XPS-8100:~/wa$ git clone git@github.com:felipelalli/micaroni.git
Cloning into 'micaroni'...
remote: Counting objects: 5238, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3257/3257), done.
Receiving objects:  92% (4839/5238), 43.29 MiB | 902 KiB/s
```

*ANY* push hangs like this:

```
master!fml.eti.br> push
Counting objects: 23, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (15/15), done.
Writing objects: 100% (19/19), 4.25 KiB, done.
Total 19 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

EDIT 2: I format my PC and I have reinstalled Ubuntu, but the problem keeps the same. So, it eliminates any problem with installations or updates. I have a Dell Studio XPS.

EDIT 3: I pay 4 Bitcoin if anyone solve my problem. Just put your public address together.

EDIT 4: When I try to push, after a few minutes, I receive this message:

```
felipelalli@felipelalli-Studio-XPS-8100:~/wa/fml.eti.br$ git push
Counting objects: 26, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Writing objects: 100% (22/22), 4.48 KiB, done.
Total 22 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
Write failed: Broken pipe
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: Felipe - is `memcached` your issue (http://askbot.org/en/question/2699/error-324-neterr_empty_response-unknown-error/) ?  Have you got this installed?

Comment: @fossfreedom, no I don't have memcached installed

Comment: if you add `-v` to your push call (i.e. run in verbose mode) - what is the output? use paste.ubuntu.com for your results.

Comment: It hangs: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1386951/

Comment: [Was an issue in the server side of GitHub](http://askubuntu.com/a/318797/169736), nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution:

after a long thread with Github support, they said it was a server side configuration related to a tentative of avoid DDOS attack that has affected some users, like me. After some adjustments in the Github server everything back to normal and works very fine again!

Thanks very much for Github support team, they were very transparent and helpful.

Quote from the long email thread:

> Hi Felipe -
>
> We've been experiencing intermittent DDoS attacks over the last
>   several weeks, and an unfortunate side-effect of some of the
>   preventative measures we've put in place is strange side-effects like
>   this. We believe the problem here was that some of our DDoS protection
>   was mis-configured. We're working with out network provider to tune
>   the DDoS protection to not drop other traffic like this with the
>   highest priority. Sorry again for the repeated problems here!
>
> Jesse GitHub Ops

Comment: Has there actually been any improvement since then, or are you still having the same problems?

Comment: Hi @IQAndreas, I never had this issue before. Have been you?

Comment: I have been getting this issue for close to a year (and I'm still getting it), and reinstalling Ubuntu or adjusting the MTU size has done nothing. Do you think GitHub would be able to help, or should I just continue to use HTTPS?

Comment: Hi @IQAndreas! Github should help you! They help me and fix my problem. I am pretty sure your problem is related with some server-side config. Please contact them and put here your story too. It is important to help others having the same issue! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Googling around for your error message turns up some stuff about the MTU size.

If possible, I suggest you try a different network/ISP just to confirm it's only happening on that particular network.

Then, you could try changing the MTU (you could for instance see what Windows has for MTU and set Ubuntu's to that; by default it's 1500 on Ubuntu).

Here's how to change MTUs: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1887063.

I suggest you first check on a different network and only then try to change the MTU. It's not something that needs to be done commonly so if changing networks helps, I'd say it's some weird issue with the network, to which Windows is somehow impervious.

Comment: Thanks @roadmr! I tried in Mac OSX and Windows and it is fine. Just on Ubuntu I have the problem. I can't even enter in this URL, for example: https://github.com/   in Firefox I can access the first page, but fails sometimes when I click inside. I have already tried to change my MTU but still did not work. Do you know what more I can try? I don't understand why Codeplane works and Github does not. Thanks!

Comment: Today, I could enter on https://github.com but not in https://github.com/felipelalli/machine-gun for example. The browser keep thinking forever until end on "Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data."

Comment: Well, I can access the machine-gun URL just fine, and I'm running Ubuntu 12.10, so it's not something "wrong" in Ubuntu, just some incompatibility or mismatch with your network and Ubuntu. If the network administrators are reasonable you could ask them for help diagnosing. I fear their usual reply may be "Use Windows" but maybe they can help.

Comment: Hi @roadmr, it happens in my home, and I did the installation from scratch. Maybe it is a problem of my computer (Dell Studio) + Ubuntu 12.10?

Answer (score 1):

I could help you diagnose it, if you disable all network applications apart from your application (git client in this case) to minimize the network noise and use tcpdump/wireshark to capture the traffic sent and received when you experience problems.

Make sure to start capturing before you run the command that's having trouble connecting.

Install both programs with:

```
sudo apt-get install wireshark tcpdump
```

and then run

```
sudo tcpdump -i wlan0 -o dump.pcap -s 1500
```

to start capturing before testing.

It would be helpful if you capture the traffic during one session that fails and upload the resulting dump.pcap somewhere where I could download it.

Comment: thank you. I'll see it as soon as I get in home. But the problem occurs on https, I think it is a problem to tcpdump, isn't it? I'll check if I can test with http.

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by the problem with tcpdump. I was suggesting to use it to capture all traffic during the time when you experience issues as this would allow to analyse it and possibly find the issue.

Comment: I mean https connection is impossible to capture the traffic. Am I wrong? Because it is encrypted.

Comment: My mistake - I didn't notice you were using HTTPS. Even though this wouldn't show you the application level problems that you might be experiencing, you'd still be able to find issues in the lower network layer which might prove to be helpful.

Comment: thanks for your attention. So, what should I do now? Worth 4 BTC.

Comment: Capture the traffic and make the pcap file available to download from somewhere as per my previous comment :)

Comment: I disabled all my extensions and the result is: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=2iCQsGRf

Comment: Publishing the pcap file would be much more useful. You can't filter through that you shared effectively.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know if I understand well, but if you want the file, here is it: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B-A1VH0ejYT7X2h1OUFsVTNUb2c

Comment: Another thing that I didn't understand is: you asked to me do it in a browser, but my manly problem is with "push" command.

Comment: For some reason I assumed you were using a browser. Sorry, it was late :) What I really meant was: when you capture the traffic try to make sure to minimize network traffic generated by other applications.

PS. the file you shared isn't a pcap file. It's the same format as the one on pastebin. I've included the exact command to capture the traffic in my answer.

Comment: hmmmm... Maybe I can do it inside an Ubuntu on a Virtual Box installed from scratch? What do you think? I have a lot of processes running in background. But can I take the tcpdump in my "push" moment? What do you think?

Comment: here is the new dump of my git push: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B-A1VH0ejYT7ajFkSU1pVDNWeUU

But I told you, it's https, so the dump don't worth too much...

Answer (score 1):

If you are not behind proxy then ignore this comment.

I am behind proxy at work and had to configure git to reach through it. Before that I had timeouts for github on Ubuntu machine while Windows machines worked fine.

So if you are behind proxy, then open your ~/.gitconfig file and add these lines:

```
[http]
    proxy = http://192.168.219.2:8080
[https]
    proxy = https://192.168.219.2:8080
```

Of course replace IP and port numbers with yours. 
Hope this helps

Comment: I'm sorry, this is not my case. Thanks. My main problem still remains, it is when I try to push things to Github. Clone and pull is OK.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting this error while executing 'brew update' in my command line (terminal):

`fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/': SSLRead() return error -36
Error: Failure while executing: git pull -q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master`

I also noticed that none of my browsers were able to connect to the `github.com` website.

I solved all the connection issues between my mac OS X Mavericks and github by switching my network wifi connection from 802.11n (5.18GHz) to 802.11g (2.412GHz).

I don't know why that worked for me, but I'm just glad it's back to normal.